# JS Second .sort breaks the first .sort in a chain

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following code. I want to first sort by last name then sort by access while keeping the alphebetical sort from the first function

```
let sorted_list = employee_list
      .sort((a, b) => {
        let first = a.name.split(' ')[1].toUpperCase();
        let second = b.name.split(' ')[1].toUpperCase();

        return (first < second) ? -1 : (first > second) ? 1 : 0;
      })
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return b.coaching_access - a.coaching_access;
      })
      .map(this.renderEmployee);
```

Comment: You need to merge the `.sort` handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the 2 sorts like following

```
let sorted_list = employee_list
  .sort((a, b) => {
    let first = a.name.split(' ')[1].toUpperCase();
    let second = b.name.split(' ')[1].toUpperCase();
    return first > second || b.coaching_access - a.coaching_access;
  })
  .map(this.renderEmployee);
```

**Example**

```js
let employee_list = [{name: "a b", coaching_access : 1}, {name: "a a", coaching_access : 2}, {name: "a c", coaching_access : 1}, {name: "a a", coaching_access : 1}, {name: "a a", coaching_access : 3}]

employee_list
  .sort((a, b) => {
    let first = a.name.split(' ')[1].toUpperCase();
    let second = b.name.split(' ')[1].toUpperCase();
    return first > second || b.coaching_access - a.coaching_access;
});

console.log(employee_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort are applied on the full list. In you case, I guess you want something like:

```
let sorted_list = employee_list
  .sort((a, b) => {
    let first = a.name.split(' ')[1].toUpperCase();
    let second = b.name.split(' ')[1].toUpperCase();

    return (first < second) ? -1 : (first > second) ? 1 : b.coaching_access - a.coaching_access;
  })
  .map(this.renderEmployee);
```

That way, the coaching access property is used to untie same names.